# Cast from int to unrelated type fails

Tags: swift

```
 convenience init(_ xx: Int, _ yy : Int) {
        let w = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let size = w / 7

        let f = CGRect(x: size * (xx as! CGFloat), y: size * (yy as! CGFloat), width: size, height: size)
        self.init(frame: f)


    }
```

if I get rid of the `as! CGFloat`, it will not compile. So why is this warning here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error suggests, you can't cast `xx`, a variable of type `Int`, into a `CGFloat`, which is an unrelated type.

You need to use the initializer on `CGFloat` which does so:

```
 convenience init(_ xx: Int, _ yy: Int) {
    let w = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let size = w / 7

    let f = CGRect(x: size * CGFloat(xx), y: size * CGFloat(yy),
                   width: size, height: size)
    self.init(frame: f)


}
```